# How to create ECDSA keypair based on OpenSSL config file?

Tags: command-line, certificate, openssl, parameters, config-files

When generating CSRs based on RSA key-pairs I'm using the OpenSSL `req` command for convenience:

```
openssl req -new -noenc -config 'server.cert.conf' -keyout 'private/server.key.pem' -out 'server.csr.pem'
```

I like to put the details into a config file, which looks something like this:

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
utf8 = yes
default_bits = 2048
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_extensions

[ req_distinguished_name ]
CN = foo.example.net

[ req_extensions ]

subjectAltName=@alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = foo.example.net
DNS.2 = bar.example.net
```

Now I want to work with ECDSA keys instead, but haven't found a way to put all the necessary parameters into the config file. Instead, I have to invoke several OpenSSL commands and specify some parameters as command arguments:

```
$ openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:secp384r1 -out server.key.params.pem
$ openssl genpkey -paramfile server.key.params.pem -out private/server.key.pem
$ openssl req -new -config 'server.cert.conf' -key 'private/server.key.pem' -out 'server.csr.pem'
```

Alternatively, I can skip the second `genpkey` command, but I'd still need a param file:

```
$ openssl req -new -config 'server.cert.conf' -noenc -newkey 'param:server.key.params.pem' -keyout 'private/server.key.pem' -out 'server.csr.pem'
```

Is there any way to move all the **public key algorithm specific configuration** (such as EC curve selection) into the **config file for the CSR**?

Ideally, I'd like to run the exact same OpenSSL `req` command from the beginning of my question for both RSA and ECDSA keys. And externalize all the details into the config file. Including the decision which public key algorithm to use in the first place.

---

I've read all the OpenSSL man pages and searched for answers here and elsewhere on the web. But I haven't found anything so far.

My impression is, that OpenSSL is rather inconsistent when it comes to CLI options and config-file options. Some stuff (like subject alt names) can only be controlled through config files, while other stuff (like EC curves) can only be configured through CLI args. Hope someone can prove me wrong about the latter.

I've tried to use some of the CLI options in the config file instead, but OpenSSL simply ignores them. Tested several variations of these lines so far:

```
default_bits = ec:server.key.params.pem
default_newkey = ec:server.key.params.pem
pkeyopt = ec_paramgen_curve:secp384r1
```

Comment: Oops, should have paid more attention. Yes, I'll try to migrate...

Comment: If you can, that would be great. Because I'd first have to figure out how to do it...

Comment: By the way, don't know if this is an answer or not, but the param file should always be the same (secp384r1 is a *named* set of parameters). Probably you'd still want it as a parameter, but in principle the file is static (and I'd name it `secp384r1.pem` so that you can see which parameters are used).

Comment: Thanks for the migration @MaartenBodewes! Yes, I'm aware that it's a non-confidetial static file and that it makes use of a named curve.
Maybe some background: I'm creating a small demo project, to show devs how to use certs and tls with openssl, acme/certbot, nginx, etc. I want it to be as self-contained and straight forward as possible. I want to avoid telling people that creating a cert with ECDSA keys requires different steps then for RSA. In the end they will just use Certbot's --key-type option, but I also want to show it step-by-step with openssl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. The `req` subcommand doesn't read 'keyalg' from config, only from the `-newkey` option.

- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/req.c#L232

However, you can avoid the param file:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 > foo.priv
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 > foo.priv
```

GnuTLS `certtool -q` can be used to generate a keypair and a request in one step.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll accept this answer in a while. But I'll keep it open for a couple of hours, just in case someone knows of a secret/undocumented way to do it via the config file after all...